# How can I select the face that raycast hits?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to use a raycast to detect a specific face on my model. In this case, I'm trying to set it to red.

I tried to use the raycast node, but that seems to target objects not faces, so it just sets the whole object to red, not the face.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Finding the index of the nearest face to the hit position defines the mask to set the red material:

[image: GN Graph]

Comment: thanks, this seems to work. Is the ray direction like a point relative to the source position , and the angle between them determines the direction?

Comment: *Ray Direction* is a vector, not a point. A line is computed, starting from the *Source Position*, along the direction parallel to the *Ray Direction*. So for more than a single *Source Position* (a point cloud for example), all rays are parallel. If S is the source position and N the ray direction, the parametric equation of the ray is M=S+t*N where M is the point along the ray at distance t from the source (if the length of N is 1).